# What is the allowed amount of electronics to be brought to USA?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, electronic-items

I am flying to USA from EU for CES and I have a laptop and 3 tablets which I would like to take with me. Can I do that without any issues? Should I fill some paperwork before? Even though I am not eligible for ESTA (I have a traveller's visa) I have read this page: https://www.estavisaus.org/news/traveling-usa-laptop and found there's no limit, for electronics, but I doubt it is correct.

Thanks

Comment: Are these tablets new? Are they 'commercial samples'?

Comment: @Krystian Will you take these electronics out of the US when you leave after CES?

Comment: @Krystian Two issues appear: a) entry into the US, and b) payment of customs duty. As to a), a brief search finds no evidence of any limit to the amount of personal or professional property you may bring with you. As to b), it makes logical sense that property you'll take with you when you leave the US should be exempt from duty...but I cannot find evidence of that, either. I'd imagine there's some way to "register" your property with CBP when you enter (similar to CBP's form 4457 for US residents traveling overseas), or to post a bond guaranteeing its removal, or to travel with a carnet.

Comment: Another option is to register the devices with your country's customs agents so that you don't have trouble bringing them back. You could use that documentation when entering the US, possibly.

Comment: Folks, I'm very sorry for the late reply. Was super busy today. My tablets are quite old, not commercial samples, regular tablets like iPad, nvidia shield or lenovo tab3, all of them are much older than 1 year. I will bring them back with me. I will check if there's a way to register them with the customs agents here. Will find that out in few hours.

Comment: The canonical way to do this sort of thing is the ATA carnet. But for three old tablets it probably isn't worth the trouble.

Comment: I have flown with three old notebooks (my main machine, a gift to my brother and the third doing server duty) and two tablets before and noone cared much.

Answer (score 1):

You are visiting the US, you will leave and take your things with you.
That means that you do not 'import' the electronics, you 'temporary import' them.

This means that you look at different 'maximum allowed' level.

Basically, as long as the customs officer is convinced that you will take them with you when you leave, there is no hard maximum. The harder thing might be to take them back into your home country if they look new and valuable.
If you still have the sales bill, take it (or a good quality photo copy) so you can show the age and value and where you bought them. You do not need to pay tax bringing back things to the country you bought them.

If they are still rather new, valuable or you do not have proof of buying, you may want to get them registered as yours before you leave your home country. An ATA carnet is the way for that but might not be worth it for most used electronics.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no problem for you in taking your laptop and three tablets into the US. You've mentioned in the comments that "...*all of them are much older than 1 year*..." thereby the customs officer more than likely won't even look at it twice.